# Null Pointer Exception Calendar.setTime

Tags: java, calendar, nullpointerexception

```
  Calendar lastEditDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                        lastEditDate.setTime(rs.getDate("LAST_EDIT_DATE"));
                        productGroup.setLastEditDate(lastEditDate);
```

I've got a NullPointerException:

```
[ERROR] [16.08.2013 11:30:43] [ DatabaseWorker] = [admin][Get product groups]
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1106)
at ro.gs.service.catering.dao.ProductGroupDAO$3.doWork(ProductGroupDAO.java:220)
```

Can somebody tell me why have I got this exception?

Comment: Obviously because your `rs.getDate("LAST_EDIT_DATE")` is null

Comment: rs.getDate("LAST_EDIT_DATE") is null ?!

Comment: @pablochan, then the stacktrace would be different.

Comment: it is not null, that's the problem

Comment: `rs.getDate("LAST_EDIT_DATE")` returns null. show us the initialization of rs

Comment: same problem I'm facing have you got any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getDate(String columnLabel)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate%28java.lang.String%29) returns

> the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, the value returned is null

Does your table allow nulls in this column?

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
lastEditDate.setTime(rs.getDate("LAST_EDIT_DATE"));
```

In here `rs.getDate("LAST_EDIT_DATE")` is `null`

Comment: If `rs` was null, stacktrace would have differed.